# Trouble with reloading data into NSArray (maybe because of ARC)

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting

I have the following method called when my UITableView reloads:

```
-(NSArray *)theAccounts {

    if (__theAccounts != nil) {
        return __theAccounts;
    }

    // Create an account store object.
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    // Create an account type that ensures Twitter accounts are retrieved.
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    // Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted) {
            // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
            NSArray *accountsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType]];
            self.theAccounts = accountsArray;
        }
    }];

    return __theAccounts;        

}
```

Setter Methods in .h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *theAccounts;
```

and in the .m:

```
@synthesize theAccounts = __theAccounts;
```

I would like to be able to effectively empty self.theAccounts and reload. So I created a resync method, but it never returns any values after I reload the table:

```
-(void)resyncAccounts {
    self.theAccounts = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I am using ARC on iOS 5 SDK. Could this be an issue? I've done similar before with fetchedResultsController and had no issues, but that was not ARC. Worth noting that it does return data the first time it is called, and returns __TheAccounts after that, until I try to -(void)resyncAccounts{}.

Comment: What does your setter method for "theAccounts" look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you reload the tableView after setting "theAccounts" in the completion handler? Also, shouldn't you call "self.theAccounts" after setting it to nil?

Comment: self.theAccounts is called by the table reload methods: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: I suggest you change your approach. First, don't call the self.theAccounts method on numberOfRowsInsection. Second, Set theAccounts to nil in the resyncAccounts method, and after that, call self.theAccounts. Execute [self.tableView reloadData] on the completion handler, once you have executed self.theAccounts = accountsArray.

Comment: Thanks, I went completely different actually, but this helped alot (especially calling table reload in the block).

Answer (score 0):

in the getter, you are returning nil the first time because the block has not yet executed

Comment: Nope - it returns fine the first time it is run. I've added some NSLog entries to check.

Comment: actually I think you might be onto something.. sometimes it works, sometimes not. How can I ensure I return the getter after the block has run?

Comment: you can't... if you call requestAccessToAccountsWithType: from inside the getter. Use the approach suggested by Carlos Hernandez